# GvrVideoPlayer.cs error prevents me from compiling the app. All I have done is import the GVR sdk! How can I fix this?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr

I am completely fresh to using Unity 5.5, and I want to start developing simple VR apps in order to learn, for Cardboard.

After unpacking the GVR SDK (leaving out the iOS section as my phone is an Android) I found that I couldn't test the scene at all due to an error that I don't quite understand.

The error message reads:

> Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/Video/GVRVideoPlayerTexture.cs(595,7): error CS1622: Cannot return a value from iterators. Use the yield return statement to return a value, or yield break to end the iteration.

I'm a little confused - I have made no changes to the project. Aside from the SDK being imported, it is still a brand new scene.

Comment: Thankyou James C. for editing the error into the correct format. Sorry for my mistake!

Answer (score 2):

Google has verified this a [bug](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/406). The temporary fix is to use `yield break;` for now. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Should be a GoogleVR bug for 1.10 version.
For a quick & dirty solution, change first lines of CallPluginAtEndOfFrames() in GvrVideoPlayerTexture.cs by commenting the return statement line:

```
private IEnumerator CallPluginAtEndOfFrames() {
    if (processingRunning) {
      Debug.LogError("CallPluginAtEndOfFrames invoked while already running.");
      Debug.LogError(StackTraceUtility.ExtractStackTrace());
      //return false;
    }
```